# MongoDb Atlas not connecting to Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have whitelisted all IPs 0.0.0.0/0 in MongoDb Atlas.

I set the MONGO_URI config var in Heroku (config key is MONGO_URI and value is set correctly).

this is my db.js code

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') { require('dotenv').config() }
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
    const db = process.env.MONGO_URI
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })

        console.log('MongoDB Connected...')
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        // Exit process with failure
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

Anyone know the issue here my app otherwise works perfectly it just doesn't connect to the database.

Comment: Probably you need to pass Config vars (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). Can you share the logs from Heroku in your console $ Heroku logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `process.env.NODE_ENV` is `production` on Heroku, so it won't use .env file even if it is under the project folder.

Adding `MONGO_URI` and `your mongodb connection string` key value pair in Heroku should do the trick:

1. login Heroku
2. select your app
3. click on settings tab
4. find 'Config Vars' section
5. click 'Reveal Config Vars'
6. add `MONGO_URI` as KEY and `your connection string(no quote)` as VALUE
7. click on add button
8. open your app again

**Update:**
I created a demo using your above code and deployed on Heroku following above steps after connecting it to my git repo. It works fine.

[Live demo](https://stackoverflow-62440309.herokuapp.com/)

[Source code](https://github.com/wenheqi/stackoverflow-62440309)

You can also check the node console by clicking `More` -> `View logs` in the Heroku app page(top right).

Comment: @Ziyak I've updated my answer with a demo using your above code. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks this helped me.